How to use variables within !reference tag in gitlab-ci?
as far as I know, you can use the !reference tag for relating to some construct used in a parent template.
The Gitlab documentation gives following example:
file "config.yml"
.setup:
  script:
    - echo creating environment

file ".gitlab-ci.yml"
include:
  - local: configs.yml

.teardown:
  after_script:
    - echo deleting environment

test:
  script:
    - !reference [.setup, script]
    - echo running my own command
  after_script:
    - !reference [.teardown, after_script]

My question is: How can I use variables within the !reference tag when the template name should be dynamically assembled? For instance something like that:
include:
  - local: configs.yml

test:
  variables:
    USED_TEMPLATE_NAME: ".setup"
  script:
    - !reference [$USED_TEMPLATE_NAME, script]
    - echo running my own command

Currently I got following error when trying to archieve this:
!reference ["$USED_TEMPLATE_NAME", "script"] could not be found

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

I don't think this is possible. !reference is not listed under the Where variables can be used section of the documentation. Could you elaborate more on your end goal here or even [edit] your example to use different values for USED_TEMPLATE_NAME like you want to use it? Maybe we can provide you with a better solution.

You can't use variables in the !reference tag. However, you can achieve a similar effect another way.
For example, you can conditionally include a different YAML template based on a variable. So, your !reference tag will be static as, say, !reference [.setup, script] but the actual contents of the .setup key will be conditional based on a conditional include. In other words, your includes would be dynamic, not the reference, but the effect is the same: the reference refers to something different depending on the value of the variable.
include:
  # all these templates will include a `.setup` key
  - local: setup-blue.yml
    rules:
      - if: $USED_TEMPLATE_NAME == "blue"
  - local: setup-green.yml
    rules:
      - if: $USED_TEMPLATE_NAME == "green"
  - local: setup-default.yml
    rules:
      - if: $USED_TEMPLATE_NAME != "green" && $USED_TEMPLATE_NAME != "blue"

variables:
  # you could set this here... 
  # or perhaps it could be set by a UI trigger, 
  # a CICD setting, an upstream pipeline trigger, or whatever
  USED_TEMPLATE_NAME: "..."

# ...


some_job:
  script:
    - !reference [.setup, script]

